# Nextjs - Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using dynamic routing in Nextjs, but I was hoping to acquire the client's IP prior to doing Server Side Rendering for purposes of adding headers for Social Media shares.

Here is my code:

```
 function myIP() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { id } = router.query; // Destructuring our router object
    
    return returnIP()
        .then((ip) => {
            console.log("It an IP -- " + ip);
            return (
                <>
                <h2>
                  {id} with IP {ip}
                </h2>
                </>
            );
        })
    .catch(error => "Error" )
 }
```

and

```
 async function returnIP () {

    let ipresponse = await axios.get(ipurl)
              .catch(errors => console.log(errors));
    let ip = await ipresponse.data;

    console.log("IP is -- : " + ip)
    return ip;
 }
```

The console statement return fine, but this error is triggered:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).

I understand that passing through a Promise is what is triggering that error, but I'm not sure how to go around it at this time. So I'm asking for help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause of type React child does not include type object Promise. I suggest you should useState to return Ip. Example:

```
function myIP() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { id } = router.query; // Destructuring our router object
    const [ip, setIp] = useState(<div/>);

    useEffect(() => {
        returnIP()
            .then((ip) => {
                console.log("It an IP -- " + ip);
                const componentIp = <>
                    <h2>
                        {id} with IP {ip}
                    </h2>
                </>;

                setIp(componentIp)
                return componentIp;
            })
            .catch(error => "Error" )
    }, [])

    return ip;
}
```

Comment: HI Viet, can I follow up with another question? I tried to pass the "id" constant from the dynamic route into returnIP but it is undefined. Would you happen to know why that is? The URL address used was <domain>/posts/102 and the filename is [id].js in the posts directory under pages.